# Word for two people who are the same age

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call two people with the same age? I'm not looking for age range or age group.

Comment: Can you supply some context, please? What is wrong with "They are the same age"?

Comment: There's nothing wrong. Fond of finding a word if it exists in English!

Comment: As written, this question doesn't meet our guidelines for single word requests. Voting to close.

Comment: @JSBᾶngs: I don't understand either your comment or the two upvotes for it. In what way is this question badly posed?

Comment: ...anyway, if nothing else I've been goaded to find an answer for OP.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, the OP doesn't show any indication of having done background research or having a particular reason for the request. See [these guidelines](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/1737/48).

Comment: I think that some more context should have been provided, honestly. What do you mean by "same age"? To me it means "born in the same year, regardless of months/days/hours/minutes", but the answers are various... I'm voting to close. If the question is improved, I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: In russian language there is a word ODNOLETKI, ODNO, means the same, LETKI- number (let) of years. The question is about an english equivalent of  the word Odnoletki. "Same age" is 2 words. Is there a one word, a slang perhaps that identifies 2 people being the same age?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally we Americans, if we have need to refer to some such group, will either say *people the same age*, or, in some contexts, refer to *The Class of 1960*, referring to high school or college graduation year. Demographers sometimes refer to people born the same year as (for example) the *Cohort of 1942*. I happen to be a member of both of these groups.

Answer (score 14):

You can say that are *[coevals](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coeval)*:

> **coeval**, /kəʊˈiːv(ə)l/ *adj*. : of the same or equal age, antiquity, or duration

Two interesting neologisms (found [here](http://tellmeday.com/en/about/)) that mean "born on the same day" are *eventsake* or *bornsake*.

Comment: Oliver Goldsmith's [The Vicar of Wakefield](http://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=The+vicar+of+Wakefield+written&psj=1&oq=The+vicar+of+Wakefield+written&aq=f&aqi=&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=1223l8890l0l9224l9l9l0l0l0l0l83l541l9l9l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=cee598fc631c5c56&biw=1123&bih=893) (pub. 1766) was one of the most popular works of its day. It refers to *the short continuance of friendship amongst the vicious, which is coeval only with mutual satisfaction.* It means "existing concurrently", rather than "starting at the same time".

Comment: @FumbleFingers The OP is actually only asking for _the same age_; I'm the one who narrowed it to _the same birthdate_. (And _coeval_ sounds too much like _partner in evil_ for me to be entirely comfortable with it...)

Comment: haha - I don't like it because it just makes me think of *primeval coelacanths*

Comment: I suggest you visit [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/), enter _coeval_ in the search box, and look at the usage examples. I think you'll find that _coeval_ works for all but very informal writing.

Comment: @Gnawme <smile> and <slight giggle> for *partner in evil*. Does *coeval* rhyme with *medieval*? Or with *hovel*... ;#)

Comment: @FeralOink I hear it (and decode the IPA) as _co-eeeeeevil_.

Comment: I've heard the term "Irish twins" used to denote two unrelated people who are born on the same day, but this is somewhat racist, and it is more commonly used to denote two sibling born within a year of each other.

Answer (score 8):

You can call them *[age-mates](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/age-mate)*:

> **age-mate** *noun* one who is of about the same age as another

It's *very* well attested, and what's more, even someone who's not already familiar with it will likely understand it, since *mate* is used this way in many other compounds (*classmate*, *schoolmate*; *roommate*, *housemate*; etc.).

Answer (score 5):

James Chandler strikes me as a competent writer and sociopolitical literary critic. In his 1999 book [England in 1819: The Politics of Literary Culture and the Case of Romantic Historicism](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0226101096) he writes...

> ...Shelley's poem seems to depend on a strong sense that the new birth of literature in his time goes hand-in-hand with the **conascent** monstrosity of Modern Criticism. [(link to Google Books excerpt)](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=RqWLrZ3UEvcC&pg=PA486&dq=%22conascent%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=JfUyT7vUOYS08QPRotj1Bg&ved=0CFMQ6AEwBjgU#v=onepage&q=%22conascent%22&f=false)

I'm aware that some "neo-mystic" promoters of Eastern philosophy have their own very different (and very obscure) definition for this word, but it's clear to me Chandler is using it in the most accessible sense *(born/starting at the same time)*. Here are [a](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=MGpZAAAAMAAJ&q=%22conascent%22&dq=%22conascent%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZvoyT-0ihPbyA4_KmdkG&ved=0CFUQ6AEwBzge) [few](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Ver-iHURIjMC&pg=PA181&dq=%22conascent%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=__kyT66aDobs8QPN5-z1Bg&ved=0CF8Q6AEwCDgU#v=onepage&q=%22conascent%22&f=false) [more](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=wNYu5RvCZrAC&pg=PA295&dq=%22conascent%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZvoyT-0ihPbyA4_KmdkG&ved=0CDUQ6AEwATge#v=onepage&q=%22conascent%22&f=false) supporting instances.

Answer (score 4):

I have found "contemporary".

Citation from [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/contemporary):

1. existing, occurring, or living at the same time; belonging to the same time: Newton's discovery of the calculus was contemporary with that of Leibniz.
2. of about the same age or date: a Georgian table with a contemporary wig stand.
3. of the present time; modern: a lecture on the contemporary novel.

**Contemporary**  often refers to persons or their acts or achievements: *Hemingway and Fitzgerald, though contemporary, shared few values*

But I don't feel it OK.

Citation from the same source:

**Coeval**  refers either to very long periods of time—an era or an eon—or to remote or long ago times: *coeval stars, shining for millenia with equal brilliance; coeval with the dawning of civilization.* So, it doesn't fit.

In Russian I know 3 words of the demanded meaning. But not in English.

Comment: Yes. Coeval doesn't fit, I have put it here as an argument against another answer.

Comment: look the edited answer, paragraph 2.

Comment: So what? People about the same age, could be OK, too. When speaking not of children, +-5 years mean nothing. In greater age, +-10 mean nothing. But I said, I don't like it, too. "Age-mate" is the most exact answer, I think. But "coneval" will win.

Answer (score 3):

The term [peers](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/peer--2) can be used for people of the same age, but it is not restricted to this sense, as it also means *people of the same status or abilities*. With the suitable context, however, it can refer to the age only, as in: *Teenagers want to be accepted by their peers*.

Comment: @JasperLoy: True. But it was the closest one I could think of.

Comment: To me, the "core" meaning of a *peer group* is that they are of equal status. It only comes to signify *equal age* in developmental/educational contexts where being the same age means you've reached the same level in schooling, for example. I don't expect to hear *peer* used of older people, or without *group*, with the sense of "equal in age".

Comment: I agree with @JasperLoy But I also am having trouble with this question, without additional context!

Answer (score 2):

I'd call them *isochrones,* repurposing the word which is used to describe a [type of curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautochrone_curve) derived from the prefix *iso* and suffix *chrone*, to denote the same time period.

Answer (score 1):

One example of two people who are the same age is [twins](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/twins)

> **twin** *noun* - either of two children or animals brought forth at a birth.

Since they are born together, they have the almost the same age. Not exactly the same, as Robusto correctly points out, since one will exit the womb first. This is as close to the same age as I think one can reasonably get.

Comment: In order for that to be true, both would have to come out of the birth canal together. Even in twins, one sibling is always older than the other.

Comment: @Robusto - you make a very good point. I will update my answer.

Comment: There's some 134,000,000 people born each year, which is around 261 per minute or four per second. I think it's safe to say these 261 born around the world are the same age and are (mostly) not twins to each other.

Comment: But, @Hugo, can you be sure they are born at *exactly* the same time? What is the term for such people, born at the same time, but not of the same mother?

Comment: There remains the case of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjoined_twins