# what is one word meaning two people who are of the exact same age?

Tags: single-word-requests

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Word for two people who are the same age](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57488/word-for-two-people-who-are-the-same-age)

I notice this discussion was closed back in February but I need to re-open it because I heard the answer on the radio today. It was on NPR, the show "Says You!" Unfortunately, I didn't hear the first part of the discussion, when they spelled it. The pronunciation though sounded like, "yeeling." It made me think of the word "yearling," but with a definite long e in the middle. I went to the "Says You" website to try to get the spelling but their site is woefully behind: the latest episode is June 2012.

I tried entering "yeeling" in Google Chrome's search engine but got no good hits.

Did anyone else hear Says You today and know how to spell this word?

Comment: If your question is about a "word that sounds like yearling" as opposed to *any* word denoting equiannuity, then open a question with that in the title. Asking directly for responses from people who heard a particular radio program is also a bit too localised, I think.

Comment: Also, are you sure the word they were talking about really has this meaning? There are bluffing rounds, where presumably plausible-sounding definitions are fabricated on the spot.

Comment: Never mind. Here is the word you are looking for: [yealing](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/yealing). (It's not my intent to flout the closed status; if there's a more appropriate way to "answer" this question, I'm happy to learn it.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I'm not sure how you can call "National" Public Radio "localized." Again, I appreciate the answer. I confirmed your response at Dictionary.com