# Preposition choice when refererring to twins

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, phrase-usage, prepositional-phrases

Let's say I have 2 sets of twins and I grab 1 twin from each set.
If these 2 non-related twins introduced themselves both as being twins but not being related to each other, how would they say that?

Would they say "we're twins, but not...

- *to* each other
- *with* each other
- ...something else??

Obviously, they could say that "we're twins but we're not related." But I'm wondering more about preposition choice in this case, so please address that aspect of the question.

Comment: My guess is ***to*** would be more common than ***with***. But so would ***of***, and I think only an extreme pedant would think such usages are covered by an unambiguous "rule".

Comment: @YosefBaskin yes exactly. This is for a comedic script. The two people introduce themselves as twins, but then reveal that they are not related but rather each have their *own* non-present twin

Comment: According to Ngrams, frequency  "twins _to_ > _of_ > _with_ each other". But that's not a good measure either.

Comment: Depending on your target audience, [*(not) **consanguineous***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consanguineous) or [***coeval***](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/57490/2637) might qualify as amusing/quirky alternatives.

Comment: huh..."twins *of* each other" sounds/appears pretty strange to me (as in I can't say I've ever heard/seen that phrasing).  "twins *to* each other" sounds more familiar...

Comment: I'd choose "something else" and say  "we're both twins" but seeing how "each" was rejected I suppose that isn't what you're after.

Answer (score 4):

Words of duplication (*twin*, *duplicate*, *replica*) as well as words of kinship (*parent*, *sibling*, *cousin*) almost always take *of*.  Occasionally, you see *to*, but that's for a poetic or archaic feel.

> My name is Maximus Decimus Meridius, commander of the Armies of the North, General of the Felix Legions, loyal servant to the true emperor, Marcus Aurelius. Father to a murdered son, husband to a murdered wife. And I will have my vengeance, in this life or the next.

Comment: I never thought of it earlier, but you're quite right that ***to*** in such contexts has significant "poetic, archaic" associations. Plus it's nearly always ***of*** with "duplicate" relationships *(copy, reproduction, clone, imitation, etc.)*.

Comment: -1 The answer is baseless.

Answer (score 2):

If you must go with a preposition, I think it's a tossup between "to" and "of."
"We are twins, but not to/of each other."

However, consider some completely different alternatives.

"We are twins, but we are not each other's twins."
(Not quite grammatically correct, but gets the point across)

"We are twins, but we aren't twins."
(Comedic and intentionally confusing)

"We are two twins but not a twinned twosome."
"We are a pair of twins but not a twinned pair."
(Accurate, can be start of further wordplay)

"I'm a twin, and he's a twin, but we aren't twins."
"I'm a twin, and he's a twin, but our twins are in another room/country/screenplay."

[Also, consider familiarizing yourself with other great works in twin comedy such as "[The Boys from Syracuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Boys_from_Syracuse)."]

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would go with

> We're each twins

The "each" further qualifies the [lack of] relationship that the two have between themselves and their counterparts.

Comment: This doesn't really address the question

Comment: how so? it negates the need to even have to say "but not to/with each other"

Comment: The question is not how to better say the statement (in fact, I provided an example myself). The main question is which preposition is appropriate to use given the sentence structure provided. Thanks.

Comment: your question was how to convey that they were twins, but not to each other. you even had option 3 as "something else??". I'd say my answer is completely valid.

Answer (score 0):

Although the poetic "to" sounds appealing in its way, for everyday speech I would use "with," as it is similar to

> I am friends with that dude.